# What would be the best practice for Visual Source Safe check-in and Visual Studio build mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am using Visual Source Safe 2005 for 8 different projects. One of them is the main project that uses other 6 project as references (DLLs from other project). And I have one setup project. The setup project gets all required files (DLLs) directly from all 7 projects’ Bin/Release folders (including main project). Can anyone answer my following questions with explanation?

1. Is it OK to check-in Solution file in Source Safe or should we always avoid it?
2. Should I always check-in project file in Source Safe or should we always avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Checking in your bin folder is not required.

It is normal to checkin your solution file. Your project file is normally included in this checkin.